# PostgreSQL QueryError when upserting into a table using a composite key using Prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm encountering a frustrating error trying to upsert some data into a table with records that use composite keys. I'm using Prisma as an ORM.

```
{ user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42702), message: "column reference \"userIds\" is ambiguous", detail: None, hint: None, position: Some(Original(139)), where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_relation.c"), line: Some(898), routine: Some("colNameToVar") }) }) }
```

I think the important part of this is the `message: "column reference \"userIds\" is ambiguous"`, which I guess is saying that `userIds` isn't unique enough for PostgreSQL to know which record to update?

The SQL query being performed in the background is:

```sql
INSERT INTO "public"."Vote" ("filmId", "userIds", "roomName") 
VALUES 
  ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT ("roomName", "filmId") DO 
UPDATE 
SET 
  "userIds" = "userIds" || $4 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      "public"."Vote"."roomName" = $5 
      AND "public"."Vote"."filmId" = $6
    ) 
    AND 1 = 1
  ) RETURNING "public"."Vote"."roomName", 
  "public"."Vote"."filmId", 
  "public"."Vote"."userIds"
```

My database schema looks like this:

**Schema**

```
model Room {
  ownerId String
  name    String   @id
  films   String[]
  users   String[]
  votes   Vote[]
}

model Vote {
  room     Room     @relation(fields: [roomName], references: [name])
  filmId   String
  userIds  String[]
  roomName String

  @@unique([roomName, filmId])
}
```

And the snippet I want to use is the following:

```
const votes = await db.vote.upsert({
  where: {
    roomName_filmId: {
      roomName: roomId,
        filmId: filmId,
      },
    },
    update: {
      userIds: {
        push: socket.id,
      },
    },
    create: {
      filmId,
      roomName: roomId,
      userIds: [socket.id],
    },
});
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information for this to be a useful question. Am I misunderstanding how upserts work, or maybe how keys are being referenced inside the table?

I was able to get the code working by manually searching for the record first with a `findUnique` and then handling that to either create or update the record:

```
const votes = hasVoteRecord
      ? await db.vote.update({
          where: {
            roomName_filmId: {
              roomName: roomId,
              filmId: filmId,
            },
          },
          data: {
            userIds: {
              push: socket.id,
            },
          },
        })
      : await db.vote.create({
          data: {
            roomName: roomId,
            filmId,
            userIds: [socket.id],
          },
        });
```

However, this looks a lot messier to me and is essentially recreating what I expected `upsert` to be doing, so I really just want to use `upsert`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the raw SQL involved?

Comment: Sadly I'm not entirely sure how Prisma converts it in the background but here's a link to the [section of the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#upsert) which has a snippet.

Comment: You could check the logfiles of your database, the raw SQL could be there because of the error. If not, activate logging for at least errors.

Comment: Thanks, found a way to make it log the query and have updated the post accordingly.